# phonegap tel softkeyboard done action

Tags: javascript, events, mobile, keyboard

i try to bind an event to done action on soft keyboard tell mode.
but i can't catch any event.
i tried use keyup/ keydown, blur and change events.
nothing happened in iPhone and android.

```
$("input").bind('keyup', function(event){
 var key;
  if(window.event)
      key = window.event.keyCode;
  else
      key = event.which;
  if(key == 13 || key == 10){
       alert(key);
  }
});
$("input").bind('blur', function(event){
       alert("blur");
 });
$("input").bind('change', function(event){
       alert("change");
 });
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a close } after the one if.

Also, maybe the selector you are using $('input') is too broad try something specific, i use  somelike like this:

```
$('#element_id').live('keypress',function(e){
        console.log('keypress: '+e.keyCode);
        if (e.keyCode != 13) {
            console.log('is not an enter key');
        }
        else {
            console.log('is an enter key going to submit');
            Fling.poo();
            return false;
        }  
  });
```

Comment: i try live and specific id and it still dont work :( the event fired alawys apart from enter